# can't insert data using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack, crud

i am new in mean stack i completed update,delete,and get data but can't insert data in mongoose can anyone help me please.thanks in advance below is my code.

```
var express = require('express');
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
db.connect('mongodb://localhost/contactlist');
var db1 = db.connection;
db1.on('error', err);
db1.once('open',startserver);
function err(){
console.log('connection error:');
}
function startserver(){
console.log('start');
app.listen(3000);
}
var contactdetails1 = new db.Schema({
    name:String,
    email:String,
    password:String,
    number:String  
});
db1.model('Contactdetails',contactdetails1);

app.post('/contactList',function(req,res){
  console.log("Get insert request"+req.body);
//var contactList = new ContactList(req.body);
  var contactdetails1 = new db.Schema({
   name:req.body.name,
    email:req.body.email,
    password:'',
    number:req.body.number        
    });


  contactdetails1.save(function(err,data) {
        if (err) {
            response = {
                "status":0,
                "error":err,
            };
        }else{
            response = {
                "status":1,
                "data":data,
                "message":"User registered successfully"
            };
        }
        console.log(response);
        res.json(response);   
    });       
});
```

when inserting data at that time below error show

Undefined type `Test` at `name`
  Did you try nesting Schemas? You can only nest using refs or arrays.
    at Function.Schema.interpretAsType (/usr/lib/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:666:11)
    at Schema.path (/usr/lib/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:545:29)
    at Schema.add (/usr/lib/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:429:12)
    at new Schema (/usr/lib/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:100:10)
    at /var/www/html/contactlistappmvc/server.js:53:25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var contactdetails1 = new db.Schema({
name:req.body.name,
email:req.body.email,
password:'',
number:req.body.number        
});
```

You should be saving a model, not a schema. What you've done here is pass an object to the schema. Documents are instances of Models, not schemas. A schema is just an object definition.

Instead of what you've done here, why don't you do

```
var ContactModel = mongoose.model('Contactdetails',contactdetails1);


var contactModel = new ContactModel({
name:req.body.name,
email:req.body.email,
password:'',
number:req.body.number 
})
```

And then do a `contactModel.save()`

Comment: i can't understand read,update,and delete,deleteall operations are performed by above code but at the time of insert type error shows.

Comment: ReferenceError: ContactModel is not defined<br> error shows

Comment: You probably missed `var ContactModel = db1.model('Contactdetails',contactdetails1);`

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property &#39;model&#39; of undefined<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at new model (/usr/lib

Comment: i do var contactModel = new ContactModel({ instead of  ContactModel.model({ and it works fine for me thanks.